# How to add a Custom Error page in an Android WebView application without any errors?

Tags: android, android-activity, webview, android-webview, custom-error-pages

The following code is the MainActivity of the app. I tried to add a Custom Error page by using:

mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                mywebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
            } });

When I use the above code in the main activity either the Error page or the Loading Icon are working at a time. (overriding each other).

I'm not understanding where I'm mistaking. Can anyone please help me fix this problem? Thanks in advance.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public WebView mywebView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mywebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = mywebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mywebView.loadUrl("http://google.com/");
    mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mywebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                    long contentLength) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            findViewById(R.id.progress).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

       public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            findViewById(R.id.progress).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
}
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mywebView.canGoBack()){
        mywebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}}
```

Comment: It seems like your *syntax* meaning is different from [what it means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax)

Comment: I didn't get u properly

Comment: You use word syntax wrongly , so your question doesn't make sens(or at least it is hard to get what you meant)

Comment: But answer is: you should override all 3 methods in one class not in two different

Comment: If u have a better syntax than that, plz share with me. I'll get it corrected.

Comment: best **syntax** has a [brainfuck programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) ... syntax: the syntax of a computer language is the set of rules that defines the combinations of symbols that are considered to be a correctly structured document or fragment in that language

Comment: Can you please correct the code with right format?

Comment: @Selvin
Now improved the formatting & edited the question, can u plz go thru it again?

Comment: @Selvin Hey, I finally found the solution on trial & error method. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            findViewById(R.id.progress).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

       public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            findViewById(R.id.progress).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        public void onReceivedError(WebView webview, int i, String s, String s1)
        {
            webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
        }
    });
```

Finally I found the solution.

Comment: As I wrote...  All 3 methods in one class...  Bravo.

Comment: s my frnd. thnx fr th idea. :)

Comment: I reformatted my question. But u haven't revoted it yet.